# Two column grid in react native flexbox

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to build a 2 column grid in react native. I have 4 square, each should occupy half width of the screen and there will be a total of 2 columns in this case.

Here is the code:

```
 let profileMetricsArray = [{
  title: localization.session_count,
  value: this.state.sessionCount
},
{
  title: localization.hours_used,
  value: this.state.hoursUsed
},
{
  title: localization.day_streak,
  value: this.state.dayStreak
},
{
  title: localization.session_count,
  value: this.state.sessionCount
}].map((item, i) => {
  return  <View style={globalStyle.profileMetrics}>

              <Text style={globalStyle.profieText}> {item.title}</Text>

              <Text style = {globalStyle.profileValues}> {item.value}  </Text>
            </View>
})
```

Inside render function

```
<View style={globalStyle.profileMetricsContainer}>
            {profileMetricsArray}
            </View>
```

Styles:

```
profileMetricsContainer: {
  flexDirection:'row',
  justifyContent:'center',
  flex: 1
},
profileMetrics: {
  flex: 0.5,
  margin: 10,
  borderRadius: 10,
  paddingBottom: 20,
  backgroundColor: 'white'
},
```

However, with the above code what happens is each square takes 25% width of the screen and appears in a single column. How can this be fixed ?

Comment: You need `flexWrap: 'wrap'` on the parent

Comment: @LGSon Already tried. It doesn't work. The content is actually wrapped. But even with `flex: 0.5` , width is 25%.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried with using Dimensions to calculate grid item? this work for me

```js
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  gridItem: width/2
})
```